# React Native Gesture Reponder inside hybrid app

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use the touch event position when clicking a image to start animating a image from that location and to the center of the screen.

When react native is taking the full screen this is not a issue. But when React Native is running in a hybrid app and the screen that is rendered by React Native is not taking up the whole screen (like in a split view mode, or in a popup view on iPad) the `nativeEvent`coordinates are all relative to the view where React Native is rendering, and not the actual screen.

I would like to get the actual screen coordinates where the touch is happening. Is there any workaround to make this happen?

From the documentation of the [Gesture Responder System](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system) all the events are relative to the root element. And I assume this means the root element of react native.

I did some experimenting and the react native `Dimensions` do give me the correct screen size. I was first thinking of using that to calculate the offset of where the React Native screen is being rendered. But I can't really know how much spacing is at the top/bottom/left/right of the view with just this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I can use [measureInWindow](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation#measureinwindowcallback) to figure out the actual screen coordinates when React Native is running in a subview of a hybrid app.

```
onPress = () => {
   this.refs.button.measureInWindow((x, y, width, height) => {
     console.log("x", x, "y", y);
   })
}

render() {
  <TouchableOpacity ref="button" onPress={this.onPress}>
    ...
  </TouchableOpacity>
}
```